# How to access code in razorpages from other razorpages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a few razorpages and have been putting a lot of code inside the Post and Get methods i.e

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveSetStatusAsync(int? id) {
}
```

think of it as opening a detailed page containing a button that should set a status on a specific order.

I now need to set the same status, i.e executing the same code but from a view (another razorpage) having the order selected.

if I put all my code in helper classes there is a lot of methods parameters that need to be sent in. i.e sqlcontexts, cache, httcontext etc. is this a good approach anyway?

...or should I just create methods in the original razorpage and call it from all other places? (like helper methods inside the class)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain and simple: if there's any code that needs to be shared in multiple places, it should go into another class that can be used as a dependency where it's needed. The listed dependencies don't seem like too much, though you should strongly consider whether you need a dependency on `HttpContext`. Most of the time, you should really just be passing in some value to a method. For example, if you need to work with a user id, pass the user id into a method on your helper class, rather than making the helper class take a dependency on `HttpContext` and fetch the id itself.

If you still have too many dependencies, then you're likely breaking the single responsibility principle. You may need multiple helper classes, or a different strategy entirely. It's hard to say anything definitive without knowing exactly what you're doing.